# Testing Microchip RN4871 BLE Module with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, beacon, microchip, sniffing

I got a Microchip RN4871 BLE Module and want it to act as beacon.

So, I connected over UART and executed the following commands:

```
SS,20
SC,2
NB,09,656667
```

I am able to scan and connect to it using hcitool and gattool command. Now I want to verify whether the beacon functionality is working or not. I mean the device is periodically broadcasting Beacon packets or not..

How can I verify that.. Is there any android application which can help or can i do with raspberry pi 3 as it has in built Bluetooth Chip

Answer (score 1):

There are some really nice apps from nordic for free available. I like the nrF connect app. I guess it will help you.

Comment: nrF connect app didn't helped me, instead iBeacon and EddyStone Scanner Application from Android play store helped me..